# React with multiple index.html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am starting making new react app project.
I don't know about MSA but trying to understand and making in that way this time.

*** This is only about front end.

There are two modules.
Module 1 uses redux-saga.
Module2 uses apollo.

So I make index.html(like a portal) with two buttons.

Main : index.html / Views : index1.html, index2.html

Each button in index.html has href="/index1.html" and href="/index2.html" redirecting to each react view. (They have root1, root2 each).

Index1.js and index2.js has typical React root DOM renderring function.

How can I load index1.js on index1.html and index2.js on index2.html ?

Comment: Would [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) work for you?

Comment: thats called `routing`, go throught the routing and make user of that

Comment: I want to make module1, module 2 with different library (ex. redux-saga and apollo). Is it possible with routing?

Comment: It should work! there isn't any special about routes by themselves, they just represent different parts of your app